# Woocommerce: How to change the item cost when editing orders?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have default prices set for every product in the shop, but sometimes we agree on different prices per item with certain distributors, so I edit the prices in the order creation.

When editing, I would like to display the agreed price per item in the **item_cost td** and get the totals calculated in consecuence rather than editing the totals and getting the discount applied.

[image]

I thought this was a base feature of Woocommerce but apparently it isn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with your shop. Try disabling all other plugins to be sure its not coming from a plugin.

Comment: I've tried disabling all plugins (except for woocommerce, obviously) and removing functions.php... There is still no way to edit the cost column :(

Comment: I'm working all day with WooCommerce and I have never seen something like this. Since the product is saved as an order item on each order, you might should trigger a new order after disabling all plugins to be sure it's working now. An order item is just a snapshot of a product at the time it gets ordered.

Comment: So you confirm it IS possible to edit item cost that way?

I've tried disabling all plugins except Woocommerce. Created new product. Created new order (after plugins disabled) and adding the new product. Still when I try to edit the item costs it is not possible for me.

Comment: Editing the item cost was never possible, I think. But you could apply some custom code to enable it. I though you were wondering why it's empty. Sorry for the missunderstanding.

Comment: ah, ok! At least now I know I did not messed up things :). I have installed an invoice plugin that can do this flawlessly when editing the invoice. However it would be much better to do this directly from the order.

Comment: Can be coded - I see no problem here.

Comment: The problem at this point is that I don't know how to code this. Not straight away at least. If you know or can provide any insight about where to begin it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try to find a freelancer on the freelance portals out there or try it for your own and ask some questions here when you are stuck.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

After so many time looking for a solution for the same problem, the support from Rednao team juste gave me the answer.
The light gray "before discount" field ("antes del descuento" in your case) is editable!
So just add your new price in the total field, add the same price in the "before discount" field, and that's it. The unit price will be OK now.